# Get Latitude and Longitude on click event from Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have implemented the Google map successfully. But one more thing has left to do. I need to retrieve the Longitude and Latitude data when the user clicks on the map (any co-ordinates). My entire code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function initialize() {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$decimalValueLon?>,<?=$decimalValueLat?>);
      var myOptions = {
      zoom: 17,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);

    // marker STARTS    
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng, 
    title:"Click to view info!"
});  
    marker.setMap(map);
    // marker ENDS

    // info-window STARTS   
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<div class='map_bg_logo'><span style='color:#1270a2;'><b><?=$row->bridge_name?></b> (<?=$row->bridge_no?>)</span><div style='border-top:1px dotted #ccc; height:1px;  margin:5px 0;'></div><span style='color:#555;font-size:11px;'><b>Length: </b><?=$row->bridge_length?> meters</span></div>" });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    // info-window ENDS 
 }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>`
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can add a click-handler like you have a load handler:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {

    //lat and lng is available in e object
    var latLng = e.latLng;

});
```

Comment: ok, but how would i retrieve longitude and latitude from object (e) ?

Comment: e.latlng exposes the individual lat and lng through getter functions, so you can do e.latlng.lat() and e.latlng.lng()

Comment: I was trying to follow this and found out that the name of the object is 'latLng' not 'latlng'. Hope it helps :)

Comment: when I click on route (the path from A-B) I can't get the lat, lng. But clicking elsewhere I get the co-ordinates.

Answer (score 9):

```
    <script>
        var map;
        function init_map() {
            var opts = { 'center': new google.maps.LatLng(35.567980458012094,51.4599609375), 'zoom': 5, 'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdiv'), opts);

             google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) {
                 document.getElementById('latlongclicked').value = event.latLng.lat()
                 document.getElementById('lotlongclicked').value =  event.latLng.lng()
             });

             google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousemove',function(event) {
                 document.getElementById('latspan').innerHTML = event.latLng.lat()
                 document.getElementById('lngspan').innerHTML = event.latLng.lng()
             });

        } 
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
    </script>
```