# Onclick event google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, onclick

So I have an interactive map that adds an initial marker when it's loaded. Every time the user moves that marker, it records and updates the location (longitude & latitude) of the marker in a text field.

What I want to do now is to add an onclick event so that when the user clicks somewhere else on the map, a new marker shows up (and delete the initial one), then update the location.

I played around with onclick listener, clear marker with setMapOnAll method, but no success. I know I'm missing something but i dont know what. Below is my functionnal code that only allow populating the marker, dragable, but not onclick. PLEASE HELP:

```html
<div id="map" style="height: 500px;"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

// fill in the fields with the marker position

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('pdb-longitude').value = latLng.lng();
  
  document.getElementById('pdb-latitude').value = latLng.lat();

document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.691219873776326, -112.83338917980956);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  // Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Location successfully Recorded ! Fill in the form below');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
  
}

// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="infoPanel">
    <b>Location status:</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <b>Current position:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
     //lat and lng is available in e object
      var latLng = e.latLng;
     /*
      *update the marker coordinate here
     *
     */
  });
```

credits : [Get Latitude and Longitude on click event from Google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247006/get-latitude-and-longitude-on-click-event-from-google-map)

if you really care about removing the markers take a look here : [Google Map API - Removing Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482949/google-map-api-removing-markers)